# HBase via MassiveRecord in Ruby is causing an abort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hbase, thrift

When using [MassiveRecord](https://github.com/CompanyBook/massive_record) over thrift to save a record into HBase, I get a strange "abort" error.

Here is some code that will reproduce the error on Mac OS X, with hbase (0.92.0 and 0.94.0) install via homebrew.

```
require 'massive_record'

MassiveRecord::ORM::Base.connection_configuration = { :host => 'hbase' }
class Woot < MassiveRecord::ORM::Table
  default_scope select(:data)
  column_family :data do
    field :name, :string
  end
end

woot = Woot.new( :name => 'rawr' )
woot.save
```

This always causes the process to halt, leaving the message

```
[1]    8756 abort      ruby massive_woot.rb
```

Retrieving works just fine, but I can't seem to save the records.

Here is what the schema looks like:

```
>> describe 'woots'
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                          ENABLED                                                         
 {NAME => 'woots', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'data', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', C true                                                            
 OMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCA                                                                 
 CHE => 'true'}]}                                                                                                                                                                    
1 row(s) in 0.0190 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a versioning issue. MassiveRecord v0.2.2 depends on thrift 0.6.0 (specified by an "= 0.6.0" version in the Gemfile).

I solved this for now by pulling off the "develop" branch of MassiveRecord from github.